# Terminal stty shortcut

Tags: macos, terminal

In Linux I can set terminal shortcut like this:

```
stty intr ^i
```

But in OS X it doesn't work, I've tried this construction with no success:

```
stty brkint ^i      # why is this illegal option???
```

How to setup Terminal shortcut in OS X?

Comment: `stty intr ^I` or `stty intr ^E` both work in Sierra!?

Comment: can you not just set an Alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command:

```
stty intr ^i
```

works exactly the same way on MacOS X as on Linux. Please note here `^i`
are 2 characters and not a <kbd>tab</kbd>.

On the other hand, the command:

```
stty brkint ^i
```

replies:

```
stty: illegal option -- ^i
```

because `brkint` is a boolean option to `stty` and not one with any other following value, and because `^i` considered alone is not a valid option to `stty`.